# where does the user_info method come from

Tags: django, django-models

I'm following a tutorial of django and in the models file (the code is below), in the class Circle, you'll see that the method contacts returns `self.user_info.contact_set.all()`. Is user_info a method of the class models.Model? and when/how was it created?

Thanks in advance

```
class Circle(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

  def contacts(self):
    return self.user_info.contact_set.all()

  def is_in_circle(self, user):
    if user in self.user_info.contact_set.all():
      return True
    return False


class UserInfo(models.Model):
  circle = models.ManyToManyField(Circle)
  notes = models.TextField()
```

Comment: can you point to the tutorial ? You are probably missing out on some info

Comment: Yes sure, the "problem" is that it's in french :), here http://goo.gl/qxg9oY, page 190 and 191.

Comment: Actually, i see the source code here: https://bitbucket.org/boblefrag/livre_django_agenda/src/963bce6b1576?at=default Looks like the code is buggy, or incomplete

Comment: Ideally, it is supposed to be `related_name` attribute for a `OneToOneField` or a `ForeignKey` attribute. In this case, it is neither, and I did skim through the whole source code. This is surely incomplete code

Comment: I was trying the code into a python shell and you're totally right, should've checked before, sorry about that. Anyway I know what he's trying to do exactly, I'll try to do it the right way. Thanks a lot